# Ragnarok Online : how to beat the Evil Snake Lord MVP?

Tags: ragnarok-online

Can you suggest any strategies for Evil Snake Lord MVP?

Is it possible to solo him, if so, which classes can I use?

As a Lord Knight, I keep getting STOP'ped, so I can't move. As an alchemist, he has neutral resistance, so Acid Demonstration always misses (does 0 dmg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can't. Well that's not entirely true, but the best classes to fight that guy is Sniper/Hunter Gypsie/Dancer or Bard/Clown. You can probably solo them with him, it's best to bring a priest to take out his minions if they're giving you any trouble (Pneuma)

He's a ghost type, so if you can exploit elemental advantage, consider that. Unless your trying to tame Alice/Hellfire, considering avoiding him altogether.